# Actions Class not working with gecko driver

Tags: action, geckodriver

I am facing a problem with `Actions` class driver.  I have this piece of code

```
Actions act= new Actions(d1);
act.moveToElement(d1.findElement(By.xpath("path of the element")).build().perform();
```

Previously when i am using `Selenium-Java 2.43.0` , this command is working fine. But i have upgraded to `3.0.0-beta2`, started access `firefox driver` through gecko driver.

At  the above specified command my test is failing . Am getting the below exception

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/21dfc828-a382-4622-8c61-89bc48e29744/moveto did not match a
>   known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds

Please help

Comment: There is an issue recorded at selenium open issues for this . We have to wait for the fix. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285. Thats the  issue. May be we have to wait for this.

Comment: As of Mar 18 2017 on that issue, it looks like "This is now implemented in geckodriver 0.15 and Selenium 3.x" and the issue is closed. But I'm having some pretty big problems with mouseover still :/

Answer (score 5):

Temporary, awful, depressing answer until they fix this is to revert back to the working versions of Selenium and Firefox. Selenium 2.53.0 with Firefox 45.0.2 is still working:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0.2/

I regret not testing against the latest, but at the same time it beats not having any Firefox tests run at all. Not running against Firefox for months on end is ***unacceptable.***

Answer (score 5):

It's a versioning problem. Selenium 3 has no support yet for Actions class driver. You will have to download to a lower version. Version 2.53.1 works fine for me with Firefox

Comment: Any news on this? Is this supposed to be implemented at some point, hopefully soon?

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me on Firefox 52.3.0 ESR and Selenium 3.5.1

```
public void mouseRightClickAndSelectOption(By locator, By contextMenuOption){
    clickElement(locator);
    String script = "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,null);" + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);";

    try {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, getElement(locator));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    clickElement(contextMenuOption);
}


public WebElement getElement(By locator) {
    fluentWait(locator);
    return driver.findElement(locator);
}
```