# Is Selenium 3.0 supports moveHover Operations(moveToElement) using Action Class?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to perform mouseHover Operation in Java but getting Below Exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/10089ef9-f491-4b9c-a295-d9246dd39e02/moveto did not match a known command
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'SHI58495EU1003F', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

- Manual Step
- Navigate to Website "http://www.fatcow.com/"
- perform mouseHover on "create a Site" link
- click on option "original FatCow" option.

Have I written Successfully Executable code or anything is missing?
PFB the COde

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class mousehover {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void start()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\rkumar\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.fatcow.com/");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement createAsite = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create a Site"));
        WebElement original = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Original FatCow"));
action.moveToElement(createAsite).moveToElement(original).click().build().perform();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: @swinkler : code is almost same but didn't work

Comment: What version of firefox browser do you have installed?  v3.0.0
======

IMPORTANT CHANGES

* Firefox is only fully supported at version 47.0.1 or earlier. Support
  for later versions of firefox is provided by geckodriver, which is
  based on the evolving W3C WebDriver spec, and uses the wire protocol
  in that spec, which is liable to change without notice.
* You may wish to choose an ESR release such as 45.4.0esr or earlier.
* Firefox 47.0.0 is not supported at all.

Comment: My general advice is to drop back to selenium v2.53.0 and firefox browser 47.0.

Comment: Note [Marionette and geckodriver are not yet feature complete. This means it does not yet offer full conformance with the WebDriver standard or complete compatibility with Selenium.](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver). I don't like living on the edge, even though visiting can be fun.

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: Actions is not yet implemented in Selenium 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41114265/1512961

Answer (score 0):

Mouse hover operation can be achieved with Java script executor(without action classes):

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
            + "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
            + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScript, hoverElement);
    assertion
```