# Action Move dosnt work with: Firefox versions:48 and Selenium: 3.0.1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

Action Move dosnt work with: Firefox versions:48 and Selenium: 3.0.1

Any ideas? even when updating the browser the same issue occurs

```
    public void waitAndClickFirstDrivingExperiencesOption(WebElement element) throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    Base_Page basePage = new Base_Page(driver);
    try {
        Boolean elementPresent = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).isEnabled();
        if (elementPresent == true) {
            //Provide a slight timeout before clicking on the element
            basePage.scrollToElementByLocator(element);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            basePage.actionMoveAndClick(element);
            System.out.println("Clicked on the first supercars link, using locator: " + element.toString());
        }}catch (StaleElementReferenceException elementUpdated) {
            element = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='prd_listing']/div/li[1]/a"));
            Boolean elementPresent = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).isEnabled();
            if (elementPresent == true) {
            basePage.scrollToElementByLocator(element);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            basePage.actionMoveAndClick(element);
            System.out.println("Clicked on the first supercars link (Stale Exception), using locator: " + element.toString());
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception! - could not click on the first supercars link, Exception: " + e.toString());
            throw (e);
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

> Exception: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/a9265a9c-f425-4875-82d6-401ff75b1a25/moveto did not match a
>   known command Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time:
>   '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38790751/2246511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because Actions API is not implemented yet in geckodriver/marionette.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233

You could use old firefoxdriver and downgrade on FF v47 to make it work on firefox.

Comment: thanks what would you advise if i need to run my test cases in firefox instead of chrome?