# c# geckodriver selenium ff

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

About 6 mouths before i found some information about this thing and it sad ff 48+ doesn't(or it's gecko) doesn't support Actions. Now i tried to find this info again, in order to understand can i upgrade now or not, i a couldn't. So now i  have a problem with selenium tests. Upgraded my ff from 47.0.1 to the newest one (51) and rebuild config strings. So tests work fine, but Actions doesn't. 
Is it still broken, and is there a way to move mouse without Actions, or i have to use <48 version?

Comment: Same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790751/actions-class-not-working-with-gecko-driver/41022723#41022723

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Actions API is still not implemented in geckodriver/marionette.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233